# PHP JSON display number if digits in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, digits

I have a question and I need help with my json and php. I use foreach loop to get the object number from my json. And when I get data from mark of mastery it displays like 13423452623423 I want to display it as 14 not 13423452623423. I just want to display how many number of digits but how do I do that?

```html
<?php
$player_vehicles = file_get_contents("https://api.worldoftanks." . $_GET["server"] . "/wot/tanks/stats/?application_id=demo&account_id=" . $account_id);

$vehicles_player = json_decode($player_vehicles, TRUE);
foreach ($vehicles_player['data'][$account_id] as $tank_id) {
echo $tank_id['mark_of_mastery'];
}
?>
```

Comment: 1: if you can't press the shift key typing "I", it is not bad English, only lazyness. 2: If you ask a question, it should be a question. Your "question" is essentially a tag cloud. Here is a downvote. Now fix your question, after that I will take it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can output the length of a string using [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php). If your data is coming in as an int, you can cast that to a string before using strlen. So assuming that `echo $tank_id['mark_of_mastery']` is displaying `13423452623423`, then you would use:

```
<?php
$player_vehicles = file_get_contents("https://api.worldoftanks." . $_GET["server"] . "/wot/tanks/stats/?application_id=demo&account_id=" . $account_id);

$vehicles_player = json_decode($player_vehicles, TRUE);
foreach ($vehicles_player['data'][$account_id] as $tank_id) {
echo strlen($tank_id['mark_of_mastery']);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. Can you show me a example code how i can do that? Thank you

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the  [strlen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) function .
see below example .

```
$number ='0123465789';// we have 10 digit number
echo strlen($number);// and result is 10 .
```